# Is extracting a ISO file to USB, the same method as creating a bootable USB?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, iso-image, extract, mobile-phone, memory-card

Trying to create a bootable USB with just my phone. Was wondering if booting would work with just extracting the files to the USB. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply extracting files to the USB doesn't create a bootable USB.

Comment: Why is that, could you give me more explanation for that...

Comment: See here https://superuser.com/a/246708/383350

Comment: You can do it only for Windows in MBR partition type and Legacy bios.