# Dual booting Linux distros using images sourced from USB drives

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, usb-flash-drive

I have 2 USB flash drives each with a bootable Linux distro.

I believe that I can use Gparted to copy each of them onto separate partitions on a single (clean) SSD.

USB drive 1 with Linux 1 -> SSD partition 1 (40 GB)
USB drive 2 with Linux 2 -> SSD partition 2 (80 GB)

I am unsure though how I should set up the SSD - formatting, required partitions (boot, root, etc.). Also, after I copy the images to the SSD how would I be able to choose which Linux distro I’d like to boot into?

This post seems to cover most of what I’m looking for but is focused more on installing the second distro:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329599/dual-boot-two-linux-distributions-on-one-disk

Note that I don’t have the installers for my distros. Each is custom configured and I’d prefer to just copy them from the USB drives to the SSD as-is. Also, I don’t have UEFI.

Thx.

Comment: What practical problem are you trying to solve by doing this? ([XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/))

Comment: The reason for doing this is that the internal SSD will provide a more reliable storage solution of the 2 Linux images over that of the removable USB thumb drives that I'm currently using. The images will also boot faster from the SSD than USB on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Look into https://wiki.grml.org/doku.php?id=rescueboot
to see if it fulfills your needs.

It allows one or more ISO-files to reside inside `/boot/grml/`
and includes them in the   *grub boot menu*,   making them bootable.

Note:

- No need to re-partition, unless you have very little space in /boot
  There might be ways to overcome space limits; i.e. hardlink, softlink, mounting... I have not tried that.
- easily change the available boot options.

You might also need to see:
[What's the difference between burning an ISO and copying a DVD's contents?](https://superuser.com/questions/246702/whats-the-difference-between-burning-an-iso-and-copying-a-dvds-contents)
[What makes bootable media bootable?](https://superuser.com/q/223664/432690)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Ventoy. I'm not sure if it will let you install to an internal drive without putting up a fight, but it should be doable eventually.

I'd start by giving the GUI installer a try on a single USB flash drive to check if it will be compatible with your ISOs (it probably will, but it won't hurt to check). If that works, either clone the USB drive to internal drive or try to install from scratch.

Note that Ventoy installer works on entire drives, so other partitions and data on them will be removed. If you want to keep the current files and the current OS happens to be Linux, then grml-rescueboot as suggested by @Hannu may be a better solution.